# Android - updating UI during intensive task?

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to update the UI during an intensive task. I've got a separate thread where the intensive method runs but I can't update the UI...

This is the structure of my code:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        updateUI();
        Thread t = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                runIntensiveMethod();
            }
        }
        t.start();
    }
});
```

If I comment `runIntensiveMethod();` the animation runs perfectly fine. However, it seems as though the UI queue is delayed until the method is run.

How can I post an animation and run the method while the animation runs?
Everything I've tried halts the UI until the method has been executed.

Comment: So `updateUI()` is a method you defined?

Answer (score 1):

You should set a priority for that thread:

```
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
```

Also check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `runOnUiThread` when you want to refresh from your `runIntensiveMethod()`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    updateUI();
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is the animation is from a library that's constantly drawing onto the canvas. So I'm not just statically updating it, the view is a dynamic animation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this, this should work.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Thread t = new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    runIntensiveMethod();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                       updateUI();
                    }

                }
            }
            t.start();
        }
    });
```