# Android - updating UI while running a task?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've asked before but received no helpful responses.
I've got a method. I want to update the UI through the method. I've tried running the code on the UI thread, I've tried posting the code (.post[...]), I've tried creating threads but nothing works.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
int x;
for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
    if((i % 2) == 1){
        x += (x / (x * 0.5));
    } else {
        x += (x / (x * 0.25));
    }
    while((System.currentTimeMillis() - t) < 2000){
        // wait
    }
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            btn.setText(x.toString());
        }
    }
} // The for loop won't update the UI until the entire method has finished.
```

Like I said, creating a new thread/running on UI thread/posting doesn't help.
How can I update the UI while a method is running?

For some reason the UI will wait until the method has finished.

Comment: loop in non UI thread and only setText back on UI ...

Comment: I've done that... the UI doesn't update until the method has completed.

Comment: The UI doesn't wait. Actually, you are not doing some heavy work in the loop, thus the entire loop will be executed within milli-seconds, So, internally DVM might decide to put the code for setting text outside the loop.Even if the UI was updated for each iteration of the loop, how do you expect to see changes in the UI happening  in milliseconds?

Comment: Can you post more code actually showing how you perform background operation? Is it AsyncTask, simple Thread or something else?

Comment: What I don't understand is why when I do something (e.g. .setText(1); ) does it not appear instantly? Why does it wait until the loop is completely done to actually change the text?

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason the UI will wait until the method has finished.

Your call to `setText()` schedules an update to the screen, but that update cannot occur until you return control of the main application thread to the framework. So long as you are tying up that thread, the screen will not update.

> How can I update the UI while a method is running?

If that method is running on the main application thread -- as yours must be if the code snippet above is not crashing -- you cannot update the UI while it is running.

You may wish to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you explain what you're really trying to do. In your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401884/android-updating-ui-during-intensive-task), you refer to an animation, yet you provide no code related to that animation, or your implementation of `runIntensiveMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should use AsyncTask

AsyncTask has method onProgressUpdate(Integer...) that you can call each iteration for example or each time a progress is done during doInBackground() by calling publishProgress().

[android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `AsynkTask` here.
It can be something like this.

```
class MyTask extends AsycnTask<Void,Integer,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
            if((i % 2) == 1){
                x += (x / (x * 0.5));
            } else {
            x += (x / (x * 0.25));
            }
            publishProgress(x);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        btn.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]));
    }
}
```

And then in your `Activity` `new MyTask().execute()`. More info on `AsyncTask` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

But does this method really causes your UI thread to freeze? Isn't it simply updating the values if you call it as is in your activity?

Comment: Tried this: absolutely nothing happens. The button's text does not update. The onProgressUpdate() method is never entered - even after calling publishProgress()

Comment: Can it be that it updates too fast and the changes are thus not visible? You might try to add `Thread.sleep(100)` into doInBackground in order to give it some time to change.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is deprecated in latest Android. (See [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) doc).

The preferred method is now to use a Thread Executor as covered in the [Android Background Execution Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background).

This is done by wrapping the task code in a `Runnable` and executing it with one of the many `Executors` available.