# Can I update the UI one "tick" during intensive task on the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, event-loop

My app has an intensive task that I'm currently running on the UI thread. It takes about 15 seconds. As such, I really need to update the UI at strategic points during the task, in order for the user (and the OS) not to think the app has crashed (stopped responding).

It seems like it might be possible to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
void longTaskOnUIThread() {
    // Here I'm maintaining the sequence of steps as a sequence of statements
    // in one method, despite letting the UI catch its breath between steps.
    doAChunkOfTheTask();
    dispatchUIQueueMessage();
    int result = doSecondChunkOfTheTask();
    if (result < 3) {
        dispatchUIQueueMessage();
        doThirdChunkOfTheTask();
    }
}

void dispatchUIQueueMessage() {
    // Give the UI a chance to catch up a little:
    final MessageQueue queue = Looper.getMainLooper().mQueue; // not public
    // Don't block if no messages are ready.
    if (queue.hasMessages(...)) {
        Message msg = queue.next(); // Isn't public. :-(
        msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

I'm basing this on the [Looper source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/os/Looper.java#Looper.loop%28%29), but I don't want to use undocumented features, since I wouldn't be able to rely on them. If there was a `looper.dispatchNextMessageIfAny()` method, that would be ideal.

Not a duplicate: [Android - updating UI during intensive task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401884/android-updating-ui-during-intensive-task) is similar, but that one is about updating the UI from a *worker thread*. That approach wouldn't work here, because only the UI thread can update the UI, and the UI thread is continuously occupied with its intensive task... unless it explicitly takes a moment to allow dispatching of the messages.

I realize that **the recommended approach is to run the intensive task on a background thread,** which should leave the UI thread free to update the UI when it needs to. And that is what I normally do, e.g. using new AsyncTasks and separate services. But that requires more control flow complexity (orchestration), passing control back after each task completes, and tracking state in order to determine which asynchronous task follows which.

This question is to investigate *what options are available* to do things on the UI thread, while allowing the UI to update sometimes. Knowing what the options are will help decide whether there are some cases where it's OK to do things on the UI thread. If the conclusion is no, then the answer to this question will help me know why I can be confident about investing my time in another direction.

Comment: "But that requires more control flow complexity (orchestration), passing control back after each task completes, and tracking state in order to determine which task follows which" -- which is why RxJava was invented.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks, that may be the direction I should go. It looks really good. However, I still would like to know whether there is a way to run just a little bit of the main looper on demand.

Comment: or do that the other way: run your `doAChunkOfTheTask(i)` in a custom `Handler` so that your `Handler`'s `Message`s are interleaved with the system `Message`s

Comment: @pskink: Can you elaborate on that? I guess I don't understand Handlers well enough to know what you mean. Are you saying that the task would be spread out over several calls to the custom handler, so that the sequence couldn't be orchestrated by a series of lines of code in a single method call?

Comment: create a custom `Handler` class and override its `handleMessage` method, call `handler.sendEmptyMessage(0)` and inside overridden `handleMessage()` method call `doAChunkOfTheTask(msg.what)` followed by `if (msg.what < stop) sendEmptyMessage(msg.what + 1)`

Comment: btw you could (i think but didnt test it) use `MessageQueue.IdleHandler` to be notified when `MessageQueue` is about to freeze (meaning there is no Messages to handle) - but still, the above custom `Handler` is the way i would go first

Comment: Downvoter can you suggest an improvement to the question?

Comment: @pskink: OK, I think I see how using `handleMessage()` that way would allow me to do the long task on the UI thread, but also allow the UI to update in between chunks of it. However it would require me to relinquish flow control between chunks of the task. That's ok if it's a simple `for` loop, but not so great if it's a more complex sequence. My goal (maybe not expressed clearly enough) was to maintain flow control across chunks of the task. I've modified my pseudocode to make this clearer.

Comment: @pskink: It sounds like `MessageQueue.IdleHandler` would do about the same thing as the custom Handler, i.e. allow me to run my task on the UI thread, but not to keep the flow control across steps (chunks) of the task within one method.

Comment: so create a Handler with a switch with three cases and call last sendEmptyMessage(2) conditionally based on the result of second task

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159097/discussion-between-larsh-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answers here and the research I've done, it appears that the answer is **no**, you can't, in the middle of doing something on the UI thread, tell the UI to "update a little bit" without yielding up control flow (i.e. have the UI update without returning from the method that's executing).

That helps me make the decision with more confidence that I need to move control flow / orchestration out to a single larger service task, instead of having the UI thread orchestrate between several smaller service tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the runOnUiThread method:

```
    SomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            //update your ui here
        }
    });
```

You can call this from a worker thread

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answers the question?

Comment: You can do the heavy task on another thread and from there (e.g. at the end of the loop) you can call the runOnUiThread method and update the UI (e.g. a progressbar, a textbox or so).
You can use:
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
//do the heavy processing
//call the runOnUiThread here
}).start();

Comment: "*You can do the heavy task on another thread*" OK. The question is, when you're doing the heavy task *on the UI thread*, how to update the UI a few times in the middle of the task.

Comment: i got it. Assuming you want to update a textview, have you tried textview. post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //update ui);
            }
            });

Comment: `View.post()` adds a message to the UI thread's message queue, whereas what I want to do is give messages that are *already* in the UI thread's queue a chance to get processed. Since my long task is already keeping the UI thread occupied, any runnable that gets posted to the UI thread's message queue won't get executed until after my long task is over, right? So I don't see how that would help.

Comment: I'm happy to try what you suggested, but I don't know what I would put inside the `run()` method. I don't have specific UI updates to perform.

Answer (score -1):

> My app has an intensive task that I'm currently running on the UI thread

As name indicates UI thread is for UI. If you are doing heavy lifting on that thread, then definitely you are doing it wrong.

> But that requires more control flow complexity (orchestration),

No. It just requires same amount of work you do with AsyncTask. Alternatively you can use RxJava. Or just simply EventBus. It's no more complex than normally.

> passing control back after each task completes

Why you hand control to computation thread in first place? Control should stay on UI thread all the time.

Comment: "As name indicates UI thread is for UI... If you are doing heavy lifting on that thread, definitely you are doing it wrong." Did you intend for this to add something different to what I said in the 2nd-last paragraph?

Comment: "It's no more complex than normally." If your 'normally' is the work you do with stitching together sequential AsyncTasks, then you're right. However it is more complex than writing a sequence of commands within a single method call.

Comment: "Control should stay on UI thread all the time." So the UI thread is not just for UI? :-) Maybe it depends on how you use the term "control". I mean it in the sense of one component handing the stick (as in a relay race) to another component which is supposed to follow the first.